# ¿Cómo puedo controlar que un elemento se ponga overflowX scroll en un responsive?

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo un menú el cual al principio esta dentro de la parte visible del navegador en un dispositivo móvil, pero si ya aperturo unos submenús por obvias razones ya el contenedor del menú crece y es más grande que el viewHeight o el alto de la pantalla del dispositivo.
En un archivo javascript externo ya tengo implementado una funcion a la ventana que también es para controlar la altura de otro elemento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen anterior luego del ítme "MONITORES" hay 3 ítems por este motivo quiero implementar un scroll a ese contenedor en específico.

Mi idea del código para dar la funcionalidad `<nav>` es en donde está especificado el menú, pero previamente ya estoy dando unas características cuando ya se hace scroll en el contenido de la ventana:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var altura_cabecera = $('.cabeceraLogo').outerHeight(true);
    var altura_central = $('.cabeceraCentral').outerHeight(true);
    var altura_menu = $('.cabeceraOpc').outerHeight(true);
    var tCompleto = altura_cabecera + altura_central + altura_menu;
    var tParcial = tCompleto - altura_cabecera;
    var altoPantalla = $(window).height();
    var altoMenu = $('nav').outerHeight();
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= altura_cabecera) {
        $('.menuFijo').addClass('menuFixed');
        $('.principal').css('margin-top', altura_menu + 'px');
        $('.menuFijo').css('width', '100%');
        $('.menu').css('top', tParcial + 'px');
    } else {
        $('.menuFijo').removeClass('menuFixed');
        $('.principal').css('margin-top', '35px');
        $('.menu').css('top', tCompleto + 'px');
    }



    if (((tCompleto + altoMenu) > altoPantalla) || ((tParcial + altoMenu) > 
    altoPantalla)) {
        $('nav').css('overflow-y','scroll');
    }
```

(Mi idea es que cuando el alto del menú más unas cabeceras, sea mayor a la altura de la ventana se genere la barra de scroll al costado de todo el menú).
**¿Alguien tiene alguna idea sobre el cómo dar esa funcionalidad al contenedor que tiene el menú?**

Comment: ¿Por qué hacerlo con Javascript si se puede solo con CSS? Asignas altura mínima al menú con `min-height: 100vh` para ocupar toda la pantalla y `overflow-y: auto` para que aparezca la barra de desplazamiento vertical cuando el contenido sea mayor. Por cierto, estás usando la propiedad equivocada.

Comment: Porque previamente a este requerimiento que acaba de surgir ya tenia una función scroll para el ``window`` y ahora que probé con tu sugerencia  no me funcionó como esperaba. Si estaba errado en el nombre de la propiedad, gracias por hacerme caer en cuenta de esa equivocación

Comment: Olvidé mencionar que, para que aparezca la barra de desplazamiento, necesitas especificar la altura máxima, por ejemplo: `max-height: 100vh`, que puede ser `100%` si el contenedor tiene una altura definida. Y supongo que no te ha funcionado porque asignas la propiedad solo cuando hay desplazamiento en la ventana, sin embargo, el menú se despliega por clic; entonces, si quieres hacerlo por medio de Javascript, usa el evento adecuado.